# Algorithm to find the maximum profit

Tags: python

Say you have an array for which the ith element is the price of a given stock on day i.

If you were only permitted to complete at most one transaction (i.e., buy one and sell one share of the stock), design an algorithm to find the maximum profit.

Note that you cannot sell a stock before you buy one.

```
Input: [7,1,5,3,6,4]
Output: 5
Explanation: Buy on day 2 (price = 1) and sell on day 5 (price = 6), profit = 6-1 = 5.
             Not 7-1 = 6, as selling price needs to be larger than buying price.
```

```
Input: [7,6,4,3,1]
Output: 0
Explanation: In this case, no transaction is done, i.e. max profit = 0.
```

Here is my algorithm. It works fine with the first and fourth arrays, but for some reason i'm not sure why it's not working for the 3rd array:

```
def maxProfit(prices):
    dif=[]
    current_min=[]
    for i in range(len(prices)):
        for k in range(1,len(prices)):
            dif.append(prices[i]-prices[k])
            if prices[i]-prices[k]==min(dif):
                if i<k:
                    current_min.append([i,k])
    print("current indices of price array where profit is maximum:" +str(current_min))
    
    res=prices[current_min[-1][1]]-prices[current_min[-1][0]]
    if res<0:
        return str(0) + "\n"
    elif res>=0:
        return "Max profit is " +str(res) + "\n"
    
    
                
print(maxProfit([7,1,5,3,6,4]))
print(maxProfit([7,6,4,3,1]))
print(maxProfit([3,3,5,0,0,3,1,4]))
print(maxProfit([3,3,0,3,1,4]))
```

Output:

```
current indices of price array where profit is maximum:[[0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 4], [1, 2], [1, 4]]
Max profit is 5

current indices of price array where profit is maximum:[[0, 1]]
0

current indices of price array where profit is maximum:[[0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 2]]
Max profit is 2

current indices of price array where profit is maximum:[[0, 1], [0, 3], [0, 5], [1, 5], [2, 3], [2, 5]]
Max profit is 4
```

For the third array, for some reason the for loops stops iterating at `i=1`. Why is this so?

PS. My algo is maybe not the most efficient, but i'm just trying to understand why my solution is not working with that specific array. I am not interested in an alternative method of solving this problem, as I have seen loads of them.

Comment: Are you sure the value 0 can be in the array?

Comment: @SreekantShenoy  yes, it can be. Either way, 4th array works fine, so it shouldn't matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, as you already said the Algo is not efficient but you are interested in possible issue in current logic.

It's the inner loop `for k in range(1,len(prices)):` where i >= k and you append the diff in your vector `dif`. It results in different results for `min(dif)` and so incorrect results later on.

Solution is to change this loop to start with `i+1`.

```
for k in range(i + 1,len(prices)):
```

Comment: yes, this makes so much sense, as in why would I try looping the inner loop from 1. But why did all the other arrays work but that specific one didn't?

Comment: It all depends on what is being appended in `dif` vector and so `min(dif)` logic. For ex. when i>k it's adding (-1*result) values in vector and causing incorrect result for `min(diff)`.  I would suggest to add some extra print statements around to see what's going on in specific test cases.

Answer (score 1):

If you rearrange the logic in your inner loop, it'll work:

```
        if i<k:                                # Is the trade valid?
            dif.append(prices[i]-prices[k])    # Update the dif and 
            if prices[i]-prices[k]==min(dif):  # current_min arrays.
                current_min.append([i,k])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Algorithm stops working because after reaching the index 2, which is 5 current_minimum is not appended as 5-0 =5 which is not the minimum of diff (which comes out at -2 later -3 you can see in the dry run or debugging)array hence appending in current_min does not happen, debug your code add pointers at diff_min and current_min you will be able to see the whole flow, you also need to add a check for is the trade valid or not

The array is the prices of stock on the given day, basically:
Stock_1 = {100, 180, 260, 310, 40, 535, 695}
so the best way to maximize profit would be to buy on day 0 sell on day 3 then buy on day 4 and sell on day 6, provided you can make only 1 transaction i.e you can either by or you can sell.

1. Find the local minima and store it as starting index. If not exists,
   return.
2. Find the local maxima. and store it as ending index. If we reach the end, set the end as ending index.
3. Update the solution (Increment count of buy sell pairs)
4. Repeat the above steps if end is not reached.

Comment: I have seen various solutions to this question. I have explicitly said that i'm not interested in alternative solutions, but to understand why my algo is not working

Comment: @Marina it stops working because after reaching the index 2, which is 5 current_minimum is not appended as 5-0 =5 which is not the minimum of diff (which comes out at -2 later -3 you can see in the dry run or debugging)array hence appending in current_min does not happen, debug your code add pointers at diff_min and current_min you will be able to see the whole flow